# How to import RecyclerView for Android L-preview

Tags: android, gradle, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

Trying to use the new RecyclerView from the support library. I downloaded the 20 update for the support library using the SDK manager.

I've added the jar file to the libs folder - and added to build path - no luck using the RecyclerView.

Tried to use also the gradle dependency according to [Android Developer's API](http://developer.android.com/preview/tv/start/index.html) - not sure if this is the right place to look - this page is related more to AndroidTV :

```
 com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:20.0.+
```

Cannot gradle sync the project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Figured it out.

You'll have to add the following gradle dependency :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

another issue I had compiling was the `compileSdkVersion`. Apparently  you'll have to compile it against `android-L`

Your build.gradle file should look something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    [...]
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: compileSdkVersion 'android-L' – gives INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Comment: How do you do it with Eclipse?

Comment: [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/) got me a bit further after getting the INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK error.

Comment: Why would a support library be dependent on the latest version of Android? That defeats the entire purpose of having a support library.

Comment: If you want to compile against an older version of Android you can. In order to get rid of INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK error you need to replace your `<uses-sdk />` declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml file with: `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />`

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Can you please share a sample project that can work even on pre-"L" versions of Android?

Comment: A common mistake:
'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rcl'
should be 
'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'

Comment: seems like compileSdkVersion 'android-L' is deprecated. You should use 'android-21' instead

Answer (score 85):

I have created using following lines and this works for me.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

For AndroidX

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2 .i get this error when i run project when i add 2nd dependency in my project. please, fix it any one ??.

Comment: My app's gradle.build has compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' already. So I tried to add compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1' - the same version with appcompat, but the gradle sync was failed, tried to change to "+" like 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.+', failed too :(

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
```

Comment: that's not the issue, what you have written is just another version of what he has already included

Answer (score 7):

RecyclerView can now be added by compiling design dependency in app gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
}
```

Comment: for those who downvote https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/build.gradle#L8 here you can see it

Answer (score 4):

If You have Compiled SDK Version 22.2.0 then add below dependency for recycler view and cardview additional for support of cardView

// **for including all the libarary in the directory lib**
`compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
// **for support appcompat**
  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` 
//**for including google support design (it makes possible of implementing material design theme from 2.3 and higher)**
   `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

> for adding the recycler view use following dependency
>   
>  
>     `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'`

After that click on Build->rebuild project and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

This works for me.
Try it.

Answer (score 2):

The steps before me are just missing one step.

After altering the **build.gradle** (Module:app) and adding the following dependencies:

> compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
>   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

(Add cardview if necessary)

You must then must go to **Build > Clean Project** to get rid of any errors

Comment: Thank man, i was struggling with Android studio from many hours, your Clean Project idea did the thing, Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Just make your dependencies like above in build.gradle file, worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I fixed it by putting `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'` as a dependency into my gradle build

(with Android studio v. 1.2.1.1 and all sdk's updated.)

It's really annoying when codes are updated so fast and the IDE can't keep track of them, and you have to manually fix for them, wasting time and resources.

But well, at last it works.

Answer (score 2):

include the dependency in the `build.gradle`, and sync the project with `gradle` files

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    //include the revision no, i.e 25.1.1
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

Include the revision(here its 25.1.1) to avoid unpredictable builds, check [library revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Above works for me in **`build.gradle`** file

Answer (score 1):

I used a small hack to use the RecyclerView on older devices. I just went into my local m2 repository and picked up the RecyclerView source files and put them into my project.

You can find the sourcecode here:

> <Android-SDK>\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0-rc1\recyclerview-v7-21.0.0-rc1-sources.jar

Answer (score 1):

Other answers did not work for me. I had to add this line:

> compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

-Go to the **DESIGN** part in **activity_main.xml**
-In the drag drop pallet select **appCompactivity**
-In **appCompactivity** Select **RecyclerView**
-On Selection a dialog shall appear click **OK**
-Your project app:gradle will automatically get updated

Answer (score 1):

I used this one is working for me. One thing needs to be consider that what `appcompat` version you are using. I am using `appcompat-v7:26.+` so this is working for me.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
```

Answer (score 1):

My dependencies;

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    //RecyclerView dependency
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

    // Instrumentation dependencies use androidTestCompile
    // (as opposed to testCompile for local unit tests run in the JVM)
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

I added only **compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'**. The important thing is to add RecycleView dependency which is as the **same version** as **appcompat**

Answer (score 1):

If you using the updated or 2018 Version for Android Studio...

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

will give you an error with following message
"Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018."

Try using this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

Answer (score 0):

A great way to import the RecyclerView into your project is the [RecyclerViewLib](https://github.com/twotoasters/RecyclerViewLib). This is an open source library which pulled out the RecyclerView to make it safe and easy implement. You can read the author's blog post [here](http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/03/unlocking-recyclerview/).

Add the following line as a gradle dependency in your code:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.twotoasters.RecyclerViewLib:library:1.0.+@aar'
}
```

More info for how to bring in gradle dependencies:

Bosnia you're right about that being annoying. Gradle may seem complicated but it is extremely powerful and flexible. Everything is done in the language groovy and learning the gradle system is learning another language just so you can build your Android app. It hurts now, but in the long run you'll love it.

Check out the build.gradle for the same app. https://github.com/twotoasters/RecyclerViewLib/blob/master/sample/build.gradle Where it does the following is where it brings the lib into the module (aka the sample app)

```
compile (project (':library')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' 
}
```

Pay attention to the location of this file. This is not the top level build.gradle

Because the lib source is in the same project it is able to do this with the simple `':library'`. The `exclude` tells the lib to use the sample app's support v4. That isn't necessary but is a good idea. You don't have or want to have the lib's source in your project, so you have to point to the internet for it. In your module's/app's build.gradle you would put that line from the beginning of this answer in the same location. Or, if following the samples example, you could replace `':library'` with `' com.twotoasters.RecyclerViewLib:library:1.0.+@aar '` and use the excludes.

Comment: i got this error: `Could not find any version that matches com.twotoasters.RecyclerViewLib:library:1.0.+` :-/

Comment: Are you putting it in the right place in your build.gradle? Are you putting it in your modules build.gradle?

Comment: where is the "right" place? i just appended these lines to my build.gradle, place it outside/inside from android {}, inside/outside from buildscript {} but nothing worked for me. i'm new to gradle and it seems to be very overcomplicated... and when i read something like "just put this line ..." its very annoying... :-(

Comment: @Besnik I updated my answer with more information about the grade build system. I hope that information is helpful.

Comment: thank you! i will give it a try in the next days :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

In Android Studio, importing is not as intuitive as one would hope. Try importing this bit and see how it helps!

Comment: The question was about the Gradle dependency, not the Java import.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this issue - you don't have to change `compileSdkVersion`, this just defeats the whole purpose of support libraries.

Instead, use these in your `gradle.build` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'`
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use + notation, at least specify main version.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Define internet permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
```

Add dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }
```

In Main Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BreakfastMenu breakfastMenu;
    List<BreakfastMenu> list;
    TextView responseText;
    APIInterface apiInterface;
    String name;
    String price;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        responseText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reponseText);
        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);


        /**
         GET List Resources
         **/
        Call<BreakfastMenu> call = apiInterface.getBreakfastMenu();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<BreakfastMenu>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BreakfastMenu> call, Response<BreakfastMenu> response) {
               Log.d("TAG", response.code() + "");

                String displayResponse = "";
                BreakfastMenu resource = response.body();
                System.out.println(displayResponse+"display response   ");

                for (Food food : resource.getFoodList())
                {
                    name=food.getName();
                    price=food.getPrice();
                    System.out.println(name+price+"=========================================");
                    displayResponse += food.getName() + " " + food.getPrice()+"\n"+"\n";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,name+price,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                responseText.setText(displayResponse);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BreakfastMenu> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Make APIClient.java class

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlConverterFactory;

class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }

}

    enter code here

Make APIInterface.java

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

interface APIInterface {

    @GET("xml/simple.xml")
    @Headers({"Accept: application/xml",
            "User-Agent: Retrofit-Sample-App"})
    Call<BreakfastMenu> getBreakfastMenu();
}

In BreakfastMenu.java

import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

import java.util.List;

@Root(name = "breakfast_menu")
public class BreakfastMenu
{

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private List<Food> foodList;

    public BreakfastMenu()
    {
    }

    public List<Food> getFoodList()
    {
        return foodList;
    }

    public void setFoodList(List<Food> foodList)
    {
        this.foodList = foodList;
    }
}
```

Make Food.java

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "food")
public class Food
{

    @Element(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Element(name = "price")
    private String price;

    @Element(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Element(name = "calories")
    private String calories;

    public Food()
    {
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCalories()
    {
        return calories;
    }

    public void setCalories(String calories)
    {
        this.calories = calories;
    }
}
```

In activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reponseText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
          />


</Linear Layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update:

'compile' is obsolete now; it has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018 I believe. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Also all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification; in addition, support libraries such as appcompat-v7 and recyclerview-v7 should not use a different version  than the compileSdkVersion.