# RecyclerView is missing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just installed the new SDK tools (Android L Developer Preview), and I'm trying to use `RecyclerView` but it seems to be missing.

From my understanding I should include the `v7` support library, but I can't seem to do that...

I can't seem to find the v7 library in the SDK folder (I did install the Android Support Library from the SDK Manager).

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440852/how-to-import-recyclerview-for-android-l-preview

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have to update the android repository, the support library and you have to use this dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

**UPDATED 30/10/2017:**

Using the `+` is not a good option because you are not able to replicate the build in the future.

You can use one of these versions. Check your sdk for updated version:

```
  //it requires compileSdkVersion 27
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 26
  //it requires to add the google maven repo 
  //  maven {
  //        url "https://maven.google.com"
  //        }
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 25
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'  
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'  

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 24
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'  
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0'  

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
```

Comment: @XuYin It is an answer. If you want to use the RecyclerView you have to update the android repository, the support library and add this dependency. This class is there.

Comment: Did you succeed running a sample code that has RecyclerView , even on pre-"L" versions of Android?

Comment: @androiddeveloper The current release (21 rc1) has a minSdk = L.

Comment: and can't you set it to be lower? I've read on many places that peope have succeeded running it on older Android versions, but I didn't find any sample project.

Comment: If this does not work (for me, it happened after some upgrade), you can change this line to `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'`, sync and compile *(expect some comile problems)*, and back to **`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'`**.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. Where can the latest version number be found?

Comment: @SePröbläm You can find all the revisions here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you are everywhere , wherever there is a mention of Android UI cards :P

Comment: My compileSDkVersion is set to 20 and com.android.suppoer:appcomat-v7:20.+" is 20 as well. Is it possible to use compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0' with compileSDK 20?

Comment: @RedM v21 requires compileSdk = 21

Comment: Because I already have the app in production, I maintained my compileSdkVersion to be 20 and set the recyclerView to be 21, which is the minimum support version for the recyclerView. I was able to get a list of items within the recycler and no error so far. Question: Why did you say it's required?

Comment: Please update! With gradle 3.0.1 the line changes to `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:x.x.x'` instead of `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:x.x.x'`.

Answer (score 21):

The only way I found to use that library is by copying  The .aar file that you can find in /extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.0-rc/
Than rename it in .zip and uncompress-it. Than copy the class.jar file in you project library (maybe rename it in something more like recyclerview-v7.jar).

Please remember to upgrade The jar when new versions will be rolled out

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that worked for me on Eclipse. +1!

Comment: @Spotlight: is there anyway you can share the JAR file?

Comment: @Spotlight file was deleted ?

Comment: If you cannot find the folder, please open your Android SDK Manager and ensure you've downloaded `Android Support Library`. It'll be right at the bottom under Extras.

Answer (score 3):

you have to give the full path in gradle build dependency

like

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'

as it will give error due to looking in a directory named 23.0
so provide full path

Answer (score 2):

Steps to achieve:

1.Select the latest Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools.
Select latest Android Support Library & Android Support Repository.

2.After updating Android Support Repository from SDK Manager go to..\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0-rc1

3.Unzip recyclerview-v7-21.0.0-rc1.aar

4.After unzipping recyclerview-v7-21.0.0-rc1.aar you will get classes.jar

5.rename classes.jar to recyclerView.jar for feature reference and add to your Android app under /lib folder

Answer (score 1):

Those who are looking for `androidX` dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to fix it by updating to the most recent version of android studio (3.3). I ran into some issues after updating which I resolved by using the "Import Project option" instead of just re-opening the project.