# How to add recycle view in layout xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop

I am following this [link](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html), as mentioned in the link I am trying to add recycle view as follows:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

I have added `android-support-v7-appcompat` library project and also tried adding `recyclerview-v7-21.0.0-rc1.aar` to `libs` but still I am getting following error.

`The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

Note: I have updated Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform Tools, Android SDK Build Tools, Android L (API 20, L Preview)

please help..

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Please see the second answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441107/recyclerview-is-missing

Answer (score 13):

You **can't add the aar** file to libs folder in Eclipse (it isn't a jar file)

**The best way** to work with the new `RecyclerView` is, currently, to switch to **Android Studio** and add this dependency to your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

**Just a note.** It is not a good practice to use the '+' placeholder, but in this case you are trying a preview release, so it will be update soon with stable release.

You can use one of these versions. 
Check your sdk for updated version:

```
  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
```

Of course you can still use **Eclipse** but it will requires some manual operations.
You can find all the release of the support libraries library in this folder:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/
```

Here you can check all version.
In the folders you will find the `aar` file of the support libraries.
Inside you can check the `classes.jar` file,the res folder and the AndroidManifest file.

- Create a project in your workspace
- Unzip the AAR into some directory.
- Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `res`, and `assets` folders from the AAR into your project.
- Create a `libs` directory in your project and copy into it the `classes.jar`
- Add the dependency.
- Use the SDK 23 to compile
- Mark the project as a library

The **Recyclerview** library has the `support-v4.jar` and the support-`annotations-23.x.X.jar` as dependencies.

Comment: Gabriele Mariotti I followed every step mentioned in link but still I am getting "The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" error in graphical layout of xml in which I have added RecyclerView

Comment: please help. I have done whole process many times and every time I am getting this error. I am using eclipse

Comment: I am getting error described on this link after following your steps "https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=165"

Comment: If your problem is not solved or for future readers , here is the answer:

Got to this location and copy .aar file from here
<sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.0-rc/ 

Then rename it as .zip file then unZIP it then find classes.jar file , rename it with some proper name like 'RecyclerView_v7' Then copy the that .jar file in you project library.

Comment: add to Eclipse Link is broken

Answer (score 3):

***ECLIPSE***

If your problem is not solved or for future readers , here is the answer: From android sdk manager download Android Support Library first.

Go to this location and copy .aar file from here

X:\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0

Then rename it as .zip file then unZIP it then find classes.jar file , rename it with some proper name like 'RecyclerView_v7.jar' Then copy the that .jar file in you project library. Add it to build path then restart eclipse so that it can be instantiated (not necessary but i had to do this).

```
          **=================================Update=======================**
```

After new Library Updates; RecyclerView,CardView etc are available as simple library projects.! :)

**File**~>**Import**~>**Existing Android Code**~>**SDKpath**~>**extras**~>**android**~>**support**~>
**v7**~>**recyclerView**.

Then right click on this project , go to properties under **Android** check **Is Library**. It is done ..!

Now open your app in which you want to use recyclerView. 
goto properties of your app Project under **Android** add Library here you will find that Library project add that (remember don't make your app a library project by checking 'Is Library'), now go to your App Project's

**Properties**~>**Java Build Path**~>**Libraries**~>**Add Jars**~>**RecyclerView LibraryProject**~>**libs**

Then add that jar into your project and buildpath .!  Pheeew.. :)