# Where are all versions of recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

To include recyclerview in android projects, we use

`compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'`.

I want to know where does gradle get the recyclerview package. How can I know all previous versions of recyclerview?

I have searched recyclerview package in maven and jcenter but gotten no result.

Comment: Who told you that that is the library to use recyclerView? The correct library is com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'` for recycer view not `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2`

All the version support library version are. you can get Support library version history here.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Answer (score 0):

To include the RecyclerView you have to add in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
```

> I have searched recyclerview package in maven and jcenter but get no results.

The recyclerview was included in the **SDK Manager** (so locally). Now since the 25.4.0 the RecyclerView library is deployed in the **Google maven repo** and requires:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

> How can I know all previous versions of recyclerview?

You can find the [list here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) and the [old versions here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html):

Also you can find [other info here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441107/recyclerview-is-missing/24442095#24442095)

```
  //it requires compileSdkVersion 26
  //it requires to add the google maven repo 
  //  maven {
  //        url "https://maven.google.com"
  //        }
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 25
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'  
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'  

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 24
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'  
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0'  

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks! But I use the recyclerview library without using
`maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
` Is this repository included in maven by default?

Comment: @XiangZhang No. It depends by the version. The v26 is only on the google repo. Check the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

A version history of RecyclerView can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

You have to use **compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'** library for Recycler View.