# RecyclerView is missing in android.support.v7.widget

Tags: android, android-support-library

F.i. `Support7Demos` uses `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`, but this class is missing in the v7 compatibility lib and it's missing in the android reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` is part of the "L" Developer Preview at the moment. [Here is an existing Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24441034/115145) with instructions of how to add `RecyclerView` to your "L" project. Documentation for the "L" Developer Preview is [available for download](http://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html).

Sometime after the next version of Android ships, `RecyclerView` should be moved into a more mainstream position within the Android developer documentation.