# cannot resolve RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I'm following this [tutorial](https://androidbelieve.com/material-navigation-drawer-with-header/) and I need to add recycleview. But Android Studio cannot resolve RecyclerView. I added dependency to the gradle file as well. And I tried to add library to lib folder as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440852/how-to-import-recyclerview-for-android-l-preview). But nothing works.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

[image]

Here is the gradle code part.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'

}
```

It fails in this line.

```
RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter; 

recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(navTitles,navIcons,this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: which specific line?

Comment: Maybe you should re-do number 8 of that tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the tutorial was not completely followed and working source code exists as a reference point.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to read further down in the tutorial, where it has a definition for the `RecyclerViewAdapter` class (which extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`).